# SQL MIN function strange behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the minimum price from a tabe. 
Everything seems fine when I do it with only the price column. But when I try to point out the other related columns to it, strange things happen... All the data     `(RealEstateType,Architecture,Area,Price)`
   from all the columns is shown ...it's like the min function isn't working... Why does this happen?

```
 SELECT  RealEstateType,Architecture,Area,MIN(Price) AS MinPrice
 FROM Rents AS R
 INNER JOIN EstatesBasicInfo AS EB
 ON EB.RealEstateID=R.RealEstateID
 GROUP BY RealEstateType,Architecture,Area
```

Comment: That is how aggregate data works. You are getting the minimum price for each group. Why do you include those columns in the result if you don't want the minimum price for each group?

Comment: well if i don't include them i get an error that the selected columns aren't included in the group by statement

Comment: You want the min price for each ________. Fill in the blank. This is what goes in the group by. If the column is in the select it has to be in the group by or you'll have to use a sub-query, or other methods.

Comment: Maybe you need to use MIN in each column and don't use GROUP BY

Comment: At the moment your query returns Minimum Price per RealEstateType , Architecture and Area.

Comment: just the minimum price of the whole table.. but also included the RealEstateType,Architecture,Area corresponding to it

Comment: .........@M.Ali

Comment: So you want the minimum price from the whole table. OK. But what does the other columns corresponding to it mean? Do you want every combination of RealEstateType,Architecture,Area and the same value for minimum price on every row? That doesn't seem to make much sense but it isn't hard to code it. We just need to understand what you want.

Comment: Not exactly... I want the minimum price of the whole table and the RealEstateType, TypeArchitecture, Area near it (to which this price belongs to)

Comment: @SeanLange For example if the whole table has 10 rows and the min() function finds that the lowest price is 400, i want 400 and all the row it belongs to, to be displayed Example: 400, House, MadeOfBricks, 500 square meters

Comment: @SeanLange So basically the cheapest rent and it's attributes displayed near it... idk if i can explain it more simple

Comment: What do you mean by it's attributes? What row would it belong to? You are not doing a good job explaining what you want here. And I think you are confused about what you actually want.

Comment: Maybe you simply want to select top 1 order by Price?

Comment: well it seems to work but what if there are duplicates(with the same price)? i want them shown too

Comment: Are there any other new requirements that you have not yet shared? Perhaps you should read Gordon's answer below. It sounds like aggregation is completely the wrong approach here.

Comment: i tried it but it returns all rows... and no, no more requirements

Comment: What did you try? Can you post the query you tried? If you would post ddl and sample data along with desired results this would be SO much easier to help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the row(s) with the minimum rent, then aggregation is not the right solution.

Window functions are the easiest:

```
SELECT reb.*
FROM (SELECT RealEstateType, Architecture, Area, Price,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RealEstateType, Architecture, Area ORDER BY PRICE ASC) as seqnum
      FROM Rents R INNER JOIN
           EstatesBasicInfo EB
           ON EB.RealEstateID = R.RealEstateID
     ) reb
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

If you want ties, use `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

EDIT:

If you want the minimum over the entire table (which *is* stated in the text, but the query suggests something else), then you don't need any of this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 RealEstateType, Architecture, Area, Price
FROM Rents R INNER JOIN
     EstatesBasicInfo EB
     ON EB.RealEstateID = R.RealEstateID
ORDER BY price ASC
```

Comment: no i just want to get the minimum price of the table but also included RealEstateType, Architecture, Area that are assigned to it

Comment: @MitkoZ . . . That should be what this query does.

Comment: @GordonLinoff `partition by` should be dropped as OP wants minimum over entire table.